# R ggplot2: create data frame for multiple ROC plots with different line lengths

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, roc

In case there is an easier way, I am trying to overlay the plots of 4 different "performance" objects from the ROCR package. The gist is that each of these objects contains two vectors of equal length, one for the X values and one for the Y values, but the X/Y vectors are not the same length between objects.

Currently I am just extracting and plotting these curves manually with plot() and lines(), to create this: [image]

It's not terrible, but I think I would have better control with ggplot. The only problem is I can't think of a way to create a data.frame() from these vectors with ggplot.

Comment: What's wrong with `rbind`? Make individual dataframes, label with new factor columns` and rbind`.

Comment: When you say your ROC plots have "different line lengths", I think you mean "different y-axis limits". Post us the commands that generated them, and try to explicitly set the y-limits or scale.

Comment: @smci y-axis limits are the same for each ROC plot though right? from 0 to 1? when I say different line lengths, I mean the vectors have a different number of elements for each line object. i.e. iteration 1 is 500 samples, iteration 2 is 950 samples, etc.. But all lines fit on the same scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ggplot` prefers data in long format, so different lengths for different lines doesn't matter.

The structure is pretty easy - you have one column that defines the line,  `iteration`, in your case, with values either 1, 2, 3, or 4 (probably make this one a `factor`);  one column that gives `x`, and one column that gives `y`.

Since you don't provide any code or sample data, I'll assume that's as much of an answer as you're looking for. You can use `c()` on individual vectors or `rbind()` on individual data frames to combine them. Or `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist()` to operate on a list of data frames.